# Why can't I build a cargo terminal in my airport?

Tags: simcity-2013

When I go to place the cargo terminal, I get the blue icon. But when I click to build it nothing happens.

How do you build the cargo terminal in the airport?

Comment: Show a screenshot please, make one with "C" ingame. You'll find it in "My Documents/Sim City".

Comment: Make sure to select or hover your mouse over the "Build cargo terminal" in your Add-ons for the Airport.

Answer (score 2):

You may be experiencing a bug that has to do with decorative items generated by zoning, or by placing on terrain that the engine cannot figure out how to properly smooth.

Sometimes when placing ploppable structures, you may find a "legal" snap point, but upon clicking, the building or module does not appear. In the cases I have seen, the funds are not deducted from your treasury and the building simply just does not appear.

When this has happened to me, I have been able to zoom in and identify the problem to be decorative items generated by nearby zoned buildings. This is most typical in industrial areas, as they will tend to make fenced in areas with barrels or other similar structures. These decorations are supposed to disappear when anything is plopped over them or ran through them, but that doesn't always happen. They cannot always be bulldozed either. Sometimes you'll need to bulldoze the structure that generated them.